# Magento 2 crash after changing to dev mode

Tags: php, entity-framework, magento, magento2

Need help for telling me what that error is so I will have an idea what to do or if someone can tell me way to fix it.
This is the error I am getting when switching to developer mode and website crashing.

```
    PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid Document 
Element 'config', attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation': The attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed. 
Line: 2 
in /home/software/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:160 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/software/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator)) 
#1 /home/software/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(69): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('global') 
#2 /home/software/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(77): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global') 
#3 /home/software/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Inte in /home/software/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php on line 160
```